# are there two known strings(contains displayable character only, ascii encoding) have same md5 hash

Tags: algorithm, encryption, hash, md5

I know there is known pair of binary files which have the same md5 hash, but are there two known ascii strings (contains displayable chars only, contains only a-z A-Z 0-9 better) have same md5 hash?

Comment: Similar question http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1434/are-there-two-known-strings-which-have-the-same-md5-hash-value

Comment: It is clear that such strings must exist. Now what means "known"? Known by whom?